# Bash function defined in .bashrc is not found within fzf calls

Tags: bash, fzf

I'm setting up a bash command utility based on [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf). I use some functions defined in my `.bashrc` to provide input to the program, as well as to handle the preview window. The problem is that within `fzf`, these functions do not work because they are not defined within its scope.

For example, I have this function in `.basrhc`:

```bash
my_fun(){
echo "hello"
}
```

Now when I try to use it to preview the contents selected in `fzf`:

```bash
fzf --preview 'my_fun {}'
/bin/bash: my_fun: order not found
```

The problem is pretty clear: the function is not imported within the scope of `fzf`. But I do not know how to work around it. How could I *export* it there?

Comment: Not familiar with `fzf` but does it help if you `export -f my_fun`?

Comment: If the suggestion by tripleee does not help, I would trace the execution of fzf, to find out why it complains in particular about **order** not found. It seems that some function (or script) named `my_fun` has been found, but is is different form the function you defined earlier. Also, you could do a `type -a my_fun`, just to see what pops up under that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my surprise, I could not find an existing duplicate, so posting this here.

```
export -f my_fun
```

makes the function visible to subprocesses, similarly to how `export` without an option makes a variable visible in the environment.