# How can I preview only a specific file extension?

Tags: fzf

I use the option `--preview-window='bottom,66%,wrap' --preview 'glow -p -w 109 -s dark {}'` to preferably preview TXT or MD files.

Is is possible to preview only those extension types as previewing is irrelevant for video files.

Comment: I solved my problem as follows: 1) Create a function: `pale() { [[ -n \`file "$1" | grep -o text\` ]] && glow -p -w 109 -s dark "$1" }`, 2) Rewrite _fzf_ option: `--preview 'zsh -e $(functions pale); pale {}'`. For Bash user, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73387553).

Comment: Inspired by [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368724) (Zsh users).

Comment: Improved: `pale() { [[ $(file --mime "$1") =~ text ]] && glow -p -w 100 -s dark "$1" || { [[ -d "$1" ]] && exa -1 --icons -TL 2 {}; } }`